Compiled JAX functions slowing down for no reason
I am using Jax for scientific computing, specifically, calculating a pairwise interaction force across all the particles in my system in parallel. This is for a simulation of the dynamics of a bacteria population. I implemented a compiled function that returns the applied force and torque of neighbor particle on the main particle and used vmap to execute all the computation in parallel. Main issue of our old simulation was the speed and I wanted to run it faster by parallelization of force calculations.
@jax.jit
def calc_interaction_forces_and_torques(p_main, q_main, p_neighb, q_neighb, activity_neighb,length, space_size,radius,w_a,k_cc):

neighbor_mapped_calc_int_forces = jax.vmap(calc_interaction_forces_and_torques, in_axes=(None, None, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None, None, None))

fully_vmapped_calc_int_forces = jax.vmap(neighbor_mapped_calc_int_forces, in_axes=(0, 0, None, None,None, None, None, None, None, None), out_axes=1)

I timed it using a jupyter notebok cell. After compiling the function, %%timeit command gave 2.1 ms of execution time on average.
%%timeit

fully_vmapped_calc_int_forces(p, q, p, q, activity,length, space_size,radius,w_a,k_cc)

>>> 2.32 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

However, I have another function that computes a single forward timestep.
@jax.jit
def one_timestep_loop(pos, theta, activity, space_size, length, radius, w_a, k_cc, F_prop, T_prop, activity_thresh, dt, gamma):
    pos = update_position_periodic(pos, space_size)
    p, q = endPoints(pos, theta, length)
        
    
    all_forces, all_torques, all_act_updates = fully_vmapped_calc_int_forces(p, q, p, q, activity, length,space_size, radius, w_a, k_cc)
    
    F_sum = jnp.sum(all_forces, axis=1)
    
    activity_term = activity[:, None] / length  # Precompute activity term without reshaping
    F_sum += F_prop * (p - pos) * activity_term  # Vectorized form

    T_sum = jnp.sum(all_torques, axis=1)
    T_sum += T_prop * activity  # Already vectorized
    
    local_density = jnp.sum(all_act_updates, axis=1)

    activity = activation(local_density, activity_thresh)

    v, w = update_velocity(p, q, F_sum, T_sum, gamma, length)
    
    pos, theta = update_position(pos, theta, v, w, dt, space_size)

    return pos, theta, activity


All the other steps in the above function seems trivial to me, meaning that, there are no reason for them to cause any bottleneck to my simulation. However, they do.

tic = time.time()
pos, theta, activity = one_timestep_loop(pos, theta, activity, space_size, length, radius, w_a, k_cc, F_prop, T_prop, activity_thresh, dt, gamma)
toc = time.time()
print(1000*(toc - tic))

When I run this code block first time, it takes 800 ms to compile. Second time it takes 500 ms or so and after that, it executes in 1 - 2 ms. More importantly, and this is the part where I have no idea what is going on, %%timeit command returns an average 46.5 ms of execution
%%timeit
one_timestep_loop(pos, theta, activity, space_size, length, radius, w_a, k_cc, F_prop, T_prop, activity_thresh, dt, gamma)

>>> 46.5 ms ± 268 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

When I try to use lax.fori_loop to simulate the dynamics,
def simulation_loop(t, loop_carry):
    # Unpack the carry variables
    pos, theta, activity = loop_carry

    # Call the function that wraps all updates per timestep
    pos, theta, activity = one_timestep_loop(
        pos, theta, activity, space_size, length, radius, w_a, k_cc, F_prop, T_prop, activity_thresh, dt, gamma
    )
    
    # Return updated variables to be passed to the next loop iteration
    return pos, theta, activity

# Main simulation function
def run_simulation(pos, theta, activity, num_steps):
    # Use lax.fori_loop for the loop execution
    pos, theta, activity = lax.fori_loop(
        1, num_steps + 1, simulation_loop, (pos, theta, activity)
    )
    return pos, theta, activity

num_steps = 100
tic = time.time()
pos, theta, activity = run_simulation(pos, theta, activity, num_steps)
toc = time.time()

print(f"Time it takes to step {num_steps}: ", (toc - tic)*1000, " ms")


some executions of this code takes 3000 ms, some takes 2 ms, and sometimes 400 ms. My simulations still takes too much time when I loop over time with either python for loop or lax fori_loop, despite the fact that I accomplished to parallelize the force calculation (the headache part) and it's execution is very fast.
Maybe memory overhead is causing some trouble but I have no idea. I am very desperate and seeking your help because this is causing my research to slow down.
Any kind of help will be appreciated
Thank you!
I expected that fastening the force calculation by jax parallelization would increase the simulation speed but it did not. Isolated executions of functions (all compiled with jax.jit) sometimes give unexpected slow answers and looping over the time variable to proceed with the dynamics is still very slow

When running microbenchmarks of JAX code, you should keep in mind the tips mentioned at JAX FAQ: benchmarking JAX code.
In particular, JAX's Asynchronous dispatch may explain the strange timings that you're seeing here. To address this, be sure to call block_until_ready on the outputs of any functions whose execution time you're measuring. There are examples of this at the FAQ entry linked above.
